# How to use jQuery to print a string to the printer

Tags: jquery

How to I print a string to the Printer using jQuery?

I have a print icon button on a page and I want to print a string to the printer. How do I do this?

Comment: just use print() and the printer dialog will show ... no need of jquery

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/print/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using printThis.js  -  https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

```
// uses jQuery "printThis.js" plugin file and "PrintThis.css" style sheet
function printNotification(printButtonElement, notificationBar) {

    // make copy of div, remove icon, add line breaks after date and then print
    var x = $(printButtonElement).parent().parent().clone();
    x.find("i").remove();
    x.find(".ReportedDate").after("<br\><br\>");
    x.printThis({ loadCSS:"../Content/PrintThis.css"});  // css hides buttons and right aligns the date

    return true;
}
```